# Unable to add ArrayList to internal database android and creating a recycler view

Tags: android, arraylist, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-database

I am trying to create a recycler view after adding data via ArrayList to an sqlite database but I am getting null pointer exception while fetching the data from the database and displaying the recycler view via the adapter.

Here is the code for my internal database :

```
package com.packr.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;

import com.packr.classes.Shipment;
import com.packr.logging.L;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by arindam.paaltao on 04-Aug-15.
 */
public class DBShipments {

    public static final int MY_SHIPMENTS = 0;
    private ShipmentsHelper mHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    public DBShipments(Context context) {
        mHelper = new ShipmentsHelper(context);
        mDatabase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void insertShipment(ArrayList<Shipment> shipmentArrayList, boolean clearPrevious) {
        if (clearPrevious) {
            deleteShipments();
        }

        //create a sql prepared statement
        String sql = "INSERT INTO " + (ShipmentsHelper.TABLE_MY_SHIPMENTS) + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
        //compile the statement and start a transaction
        SQLiteStatement statement = mDatabase.compileStatement(sql);
        mDatabase.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < shipmentArrayList.size(); i++) {
            Shipment current = shipmentArrayList.get(i);
            statement.clearBindings();
            //for a given column index, simply bind the data to be put inside that index
            statement.bindString(2,current.getRecipientName());
            statement.bindString(3,current.getRecipientContact());
            statement.bindString(4, current.getItemQuantity());
            statement.bindString(5, current.getItemType());
            statement.bindString(6, current.getDeliveryType());
            statement.bindString(7, current.getStreetNo());
            statement.bindString(8, current.getRoute());
            statement.bindString(9, current.getState());
            statement.bindString(10, current.getCity());
            statement.bindString(11, current.getPostalCode());
            statement.bindDouble(12,current.getLatitude());
            statement.bindDouble(13, current.getLongitude());

            statement.execute();
        }
        //set the transaction as successful and end the transaction
        L.m("inserting entries " + shipmentArrayList.size() + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        mDatabase.endTransaction();
    }

    public ArrayList<Shipment> readShipments() {
        ArrayList<Shipment> shipmentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        //get a list of columns to be retrieved, we need all of them
        String[] columns = {
                ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_ID,
                ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_RECIPIENT_NAME,
                ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_RECIPIENT_CONTACT,
                ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_QUANTITY,
                ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_TYPE,
                ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_DELIVERY_TYPE,
                ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_STREET_NO,
                ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_ROUTE,
                ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_LOCALITY,
                ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_CITY,
                ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_POSTAL_CODE,
                ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE,
                ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE
        };
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query((ShipmentsHelper.TABLE_MY_SHIPMENTS), columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            L.m("loading entries " + cursor.getCount() + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            do {

                //create a new movie object and retrieve the data from the cursor to be stored in this movie object
                Shipment shipment = new Shipment();
                //each step is a 2 part process, find the index of the column first, find the data of that column using
                //that index and finally set our blank movie object to contain our data
                shipment.setRecipientName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_RECIPIENT_NAME)));
                shipment.setRecipientContact(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_RECIPIENT_CONTACT)));
                shipment.setItemQuantity(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_QUANTITY)));
                shipment.setItemType(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_TYPE)));
                shipment.setDeliveryType(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_DELIVERY_TYPE)));
                shipment.setStreetNo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_STREET_NO)));
                shipment.setRoute(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_ROUTE)));
                shipment.setCity(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_LOCALITY)));
                shipment.setState(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_CITY)));
                shipment.setPostalCode(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_POSTAL_CODE)));
                shipment.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE)));
                shipment.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShipmentsHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE)));
                //add the task to the list of task objects which we plan to return
                shipmentArrayList.add(shipment);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return shipmentArrayList;
    }

    public void deleteShipments() {
        mDatabase.delete((ShipmentsHelper.TABLE_MY_SHIPMENTS), null, null);
    }

    private static class ShipmentsHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static final String TABLE_MY_SHIPMENTS = "my_shipments";
        public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_RECIPIENT_NAME = "recipientName";
        public static final String COLUMN_RECIPIENT_CONTACT = "recipientContact";
        public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_QUANTITY = "itemQuantity";
        public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_TYPE = "itemType";
        public static final String COLUMN_DELIVERY_TYPE = "deliveryType";
        public static final String COLUMN_STREET_NO = "streetNo";
        public static final String COLUMN_ROUTE = "route";
        public static final String COLUMN_LOCALITY = "locality";
        public static final String COLUMN_CITY = "city";
        public static final String COLUMN_POSTAL_CODE = "postalCode";
        public static final String COLUMN_LATITUDE = "latitude";
        public static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE = "longitude";

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MY_SHIPMENTS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MY_SHIPMENTS + " (" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                COLUMN_RECIPIENT_NAME + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_RECIPIENT_CONTACT + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_ITEM_QUANTITY + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_ITEM_TYPE + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_DELIVERY_TYPE + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_STREET_NO + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_ROUTE + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_LOCALITY + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_CITY + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_POSTAL_CODE + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_LATITUDE + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_LONGITUDE + " TEXT" +
                ");";

        private static final String DB_NAME = "my_shipments_db";
        private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
        private Context mContext;

        public ShipmentsHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MY_SHIPMENTS);
                L.m("create table shipments executed");
            } catch (SQLiteException exception) {
                L.t(mContext, exception + "");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try {
                L.m("upgrade table shipments executed");
                db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE " + TABLE_MY_SHIPMENTS + " IF EXISTS;");
                onCreate(db);
            } catch (SQLiteException exception) {
                L.t(mContext, exception + "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have initialized the recycler view and fetching the recycler view from the internal database if it is not empty in this activity :

```
package com.packr.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.packr.R;
import com.packr.adapters.ShipmentsAdapter;
import com.packr.classes.Packr;
import com.packr.classes.SharedPreferenceClass;
import com.packr.classes.Shipment;
import com.packr.database.DBShipments;
import com.packr.logging.L;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyShipmentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String STATE_SHIPMENTS = "state_shipments";
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ShipmentsAdapter mShipmentAdapter;
    private SharedPreferenceClass preferenceClass;
    private Button addShipment;
    private LinearLayout askForPickup;
    private MyShipmentsActivity activity;
    private ArrayList<Shipment> shipmentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_shipments);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("My shipments");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        initialize();
        onClick();

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            //if this fragment starts after a rotation or configuration change, load the existing movies from a parcelable
            shipmentArrayList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_SHIPMENTS);
        } else {

            shipmentArrayList = Packr.getWritableDatabase().readShipments();

            if (shipmentArrayList.isEmpty()) {
                L.T(getApplicationContext(), "No shipments found");
            }
        }

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.shipments_recycler_view);
        mShipmentAdapter = new ShipmentsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), activity);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mShipmentAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        mShipmentAdapter.setShipmentArrayList(shipmentArrayList);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my_shipments, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void initialize() {
        addShipment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_shipment);
        askForPickup = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.askForPickup);
    }

    public void onClick() {
        addShipment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!shipmentArrayList.isEmpty()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyShipmentsActivity.this, DeliveryAddressSearchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyShipmentsActivity.this, PickupAddressSearchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        askForPickup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (shipmentArrayList.isEmpty()) {
                    L.T(getApplicationContext(), "No shipments found");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to insert data to the internal database from this activity. I have initialized the adapter here but getting a null pointer exception when I am trying to set the Arraylist to the adapter here.

Here is the code of the activity :

```
package com.packr.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.avast.android.dialogs.fragment.SimpleDialogFragment;
import com.avast.android.dialogs.iface.ISimpleDialogListener;
import com.kbeanie.imagechooser.api.ChooserType;
import com.kbeanie.imagechooser.api.ChosenImage;
import com.kbeanie.imagechooser.api.ImageChooserListener;
import com.kbeanie.imagechooser.api.ImageChooserManager;
import com.packr.R;
import com.packr.adapters.ShipmentsAdapter;
import com.packr.classes.Packr;
import com.packr.classes.Shipment;
import com.packr.database.DBShipments;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ItemDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ISimpleDialogListener, ImageChooserListener {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ImageChooserManager imageChooserManager;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private TextView addImage;
    private Bitmap myBitmap;
    private ShipmentsAdapter mShipmentAdapter;
    private ImageView itemImage;
    private TextInputLayout itemDescriptionText, quantityText, valueOfItemText;
    private EditText itemDescription, quantity, valueOfItem;
    private TextView weightUnit, weightValue, selectWeight;
    private ArrayList<Shipment> shipmentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_details);
        initialize();
        onClick();


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Item details");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (checkedId == R.id.parcelRadioButton) {
                    weightUnit.setText("kg");
                    selectWeight.setText("Select weight of item");
                    if (seekBar.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    seekBar.setProgress(5);
                    weightValue.setText(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));
                } else {
                    seekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    weightUnit.setText("gm");
                    selectWeight.setText("Permitted weight");
                    weightValue.setText("upto 500");

                }

            }
        });

        seekBar.setProgress(1);
        seekBar.incrementProgressBy(5);
        seekBar.setMax(15);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                progress = progress / 5;
                progress = progress * 5;
                weightValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item_details, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_done) {
            if (validationCheck()) {
                Shipment shipment = new Shipment();
                shipment.setRecipientName(getIntent().getExtras().getString("recipientName"));
                shipment.setRecipientContact(getIntent().getExtras().getString("recipientContact"));
                shipment.setCity(getIntent().getExtras().getString("city"));
                shipment.setState(getIntent().getExtras().getString("state"));
                shipment.setStreetNo(getIntent().getExtras().getString("street"));
                shipment.setPostalCode(getIntent().getExtras().getString("pincode"));
                shipmentArrayList.add(shipment);
               **mShipmentAdapter.setShipmentArrayList(shipmentArrayList);
                Packr.getWritableDatabase().insertShipment(shipmentArrayList, true);**
                Intent intent = new Intent(ItemDetailsActivity.this, MyShipmentsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void initialize() {
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        weightUnit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weightUnit);
        weightValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weightValue);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioPackageSize);
        selectWeight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectWeight);
        addImage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addImage);
        itemImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        itemDescriptionText = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.item_description_text_input_layout);
        quantityText = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.item_quantity_text_input_layout);
        valueOfItemText = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.item_value_text_input_layout);
        itemDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.item_description_edit_text);
        quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.item_quantity_edit_text);
        valueOfItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.item_value_edit_text);

    }

    public void onClick() {
        addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDialogFragment.createBuilder(getApplicationContext(), getSupportFragmentManager()).setTitle("Choose item image").setMessage(R.string.selectImage).setNegativeButtonText("Gallery").setPositiveButtonText("Camera").show();
            }
        });
    }

    public Boolean validationCheck() {
        if (itemDescription.getText().length() == 0) {
            itemDescriptionText.setErrorEnabled(true);
            itemDescriptionText.setError("Please provide an item description");
        } else if (quantity.getText().length() == 0) {
            quantityText.setErrorEnabled(true);
            quantityText.setError("Provide item quantity");
        } else if (valueOfItem.getText().length() == 0) {
            valueOfItemText.setErrorEnabled(true);
            valueOfItemText.setError("Please provide value of item");
        } else {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void chooseImage() {
        imageChooserManager = new ImageChooserManager(this,
                ChooserType.REQUEST_PICK_PICTURE);
        imageChooserManager.setImageChooserListener(this);
        try {
            imageChooserManager.choose();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void snapImage() {
        imageChooserManager = new ImageChooserManager(this, ChooserType.REQUEST_CAPTURE_PICTURE);
        imageChooserManager.setImageChooserListener(this);
        try {
            imageChooserManager.choose();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onNegativeButtonClicked(int i) {
        chooseImage();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNeutralButtonClicked(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPositiveButtonClicked(int i) {
        snapImage();
    }

    @Override
    public void onImageChosen(ChosenImage chosenImage) {

        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(chosenImage.getFileThumbnail());
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                itemImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
                (requestCode == ChooserType.REQUEST_PICK_PICTURE ||
                        requestCode == ChooserType.REQUEST_CAPTURE_PICTURE)) {
            imageChooserManager.submit(requestCode, data);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onError(String s) {

    }
}
```

This is the error message I am getting :

```
 Process: com.packr, PID: 11838
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.packr/com.packr.activities.MyShipmentsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2190)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2239)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5047)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.packr.adapters.ShipmentsAdapter.setShipmentArrayList(ShipmentsAdapter.java:72)
            at com.packr.activities.MyShipmentsActivity.onCreate(MyShipmentsActivity.java:66)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5249)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2239)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5047)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake from my end.

1) I did not initialize the adapter in itemDetails activity
2) Secondly the data being passed in the intent was null.

Fixing the above things solved the issue.